# Not ignoring first character in c++

Tags: c++, getline

I am trying to read a line of characters but only outputting the second and fourth character. I am having trouble ignoring the first character.  I have to use the get,peek, and ignore functions. This is my code!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

char char2, char4;

cout << "Enter an arbitary line. "<<endl;



cin.get(char2);
cout << char2;
cin.get(char4);
cout << char4;

cin.ignore(1, '\n');


cin.peek();
cin.get(char2);
cout << char2 << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So if i input     ~12/.derg it outputs ~1/

Comment: Your code isn't even trying to do what you described. What do you expect the first cin.get(char2) do? What do you think printing char2 afterwards will do?  Here is the referefence to istrream (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) I suggest you read the functions and what they do, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is to keep reading from the input stream and put the reading expression in the while loop itself like in the code below, this way the loop automatically exits without having to check explicitly

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto ch = char{};
    auto counter = 0;

    while (cin.get(ch)) {
        counter++;
        if (ch == '\n') {
            counter = 0;
            continue;
        } else if (counter == 2 || counter == 4) {
            cout << ch;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is with a character array...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

char characterArray[4];
cout << "please enter four characters: ";
cin >> characterArray;
cout << characterArray[1] << " " << characterArray[3];

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::getline` to read one line and print the second and fourth character if possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        int n = line.size();
        if (n >= 2) {
            std::cout << line[1] << "\n";
        }
        if (n >= 4) {
            std::cout << line[3] << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```